# How do I stop an Azure website from using CPU time when it is already suspended?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a Windows Azure Web Site that recently got temporarily suspended due to CPU usage quotas. That's fine, I'd normally let it reset and continue on. But CPU usage has been extremely high for the last 12 hours now and doesn't seem to be stopping despite the site being suspended. Because it is suspended, there's been no data out, no incoming requests to process, nothing. So what the heck is suddenly using all of this CPU power? This site has been running just fine, well under quota, for months without any deployments/code changes.

In lieu of determining the cause of the high CPU usage, I'm more concerned with simply getting it to stop now. As it is, every time the CPU quota resets it immediately gets suspended again since usage is still so ridiculously high.

**Is there some way I can kill the process/site?** The Stop/Restart buttons are missing from the Azure Management portal (I'm guessing because it is suspended), but despite being suspended for so long now it is still consistently eating up CPU. (On the activity graph, CPU usage spiked sometime yesterday afternoon and has been plateaued since.)

Answer (score 1):

This is very odd, and not what I would expect to see happen.  You have a few options to try:

1. Attempt to use PowerShell to stop the web site.  You can download the Windows Azure PowerShell Cmdlets at http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/downloads/.  The Stop-AzureWebsite cmdlet is what you'll want to use.  If you are unfamiliar with the PowerShell cmdlets there are some [examples and info on Microsoft's website](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/install-and-configure-windows-powershell/).
2. Put in a support ticket if you have a [support plan](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/plans/).  If you don't have a support plan you can also put in a post on the MSDN Forums which is seen by support folks more than they are here I think.  There is no SLA or such with the free accounts, but they see these and do investigate.  Just might take some time.
3. If you for sure want to stop it one option is to attempt to delete it if that option is still available to you in the portal.  If you don't see this in the portal either then there is a PowerShell CmdLet Remove-AzureWebsite which does this operation.  **This will also take out the code and data for the site unless that data is persisted outside of the web site environment** (like to a database).  This might be your last resort and hopefully you have the content of the site backed up or as part of source control somewhere.  If not, attempt to get to it using FTP.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try the PowerShell option in the morning. If that doesn't work, I probably just try deleting the whole thing. Source code is auto-deployed from a git repo so not worried about losing any files.

Comment: After finally getting the PS certs set up, I tried stopping it and... nothing. Running the cmdlet with -Debug shows that it is issuing the stop correctly and no errors occur, but it just doesn't seem to have any effect. I think because it is suspended (hence why there's no Stop exposed on the web site perhaps). So I just deleted the entire site from Azure. Since that is a nuclear bomb approach it's not really a solution, though. Hopefully nobody else has this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Add an app_offline.htm to the root of the site it will cause iis to stop the application.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/10/06/426755.aspx

It does sound like you have a piece of code in a loop though are you using threads in the site?

**Edit**

As I have never run into this situation I don't know if your ftp actions are also blocked

Comment: Thankfully, FTP still works. I used that to try to snoop around in the log files but didn't find anything useful.

Comment: That's a shame you didn't find anything maybe raise this with Microsoft as you should have been able to kill the site.